# docker does not start after apt upgrade (Community Edition)

Tags: debian, docker

I updated `docker-ce` on my debian 10 inside a VM on XEN with pygrub.

after this upgrade I upgraded to Debian 11, but the error stayed the same.

I am on docker-ce        version                     5:23.0.0-1~debian.11~bullseye now
and I get this error messages when trying to restart the daemon:

```
Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
level=warning msg="failed to rename /var/lib/docker/tmp for background deletion: rename /var/lib/docker/tmp /var/lib/docker/tmp-old: file exists. Del
eting synchronously" [Channel #1] Channel created" module=grpc                                                                                     
[Channel #1] original dial target is: \"unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock\"" module=grpc                                 
[Channel #1] parsed dial target is: {Scheme:unix Authority: Endpoint:run/containerd/containerd.sock URL:{Scheme:unix Opaque: U
ser: Host: Path:/run/containerd/containerd.sock RawPath: OmitHost:false ForceQuery:false RawQuery: Fragment: RawFragment:}}" module=grpc [Channel #1] Channel authority set to \"localhost\"" module=grpc                                                              
[Channel #1] Resolver state updated: {\n  \"Addresses\": [\n    {\n      \"Addr\": \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\",\n \"ServerName\": \"\",\n      \"Attributes\": {},\n      \"BalancerAttributes\": null,\n      \"Type\": 0,\n      \"Metadata\": null\n    }\n  ],\n  \"ServiceConfig\": null,\n  \"Attributes\": null\n} (resolver returned new addresses)" module=grpc [Channel #1] Channel switches to new LB policy \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
[Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel created" module=grpc                                                           [8/13043]
[Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc                                          
[Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel picks a new address \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" to connect" module=grpc         
[Channel #1] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc                                                           
[Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc                                               
[Channel #1] Channel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc                                                                
[Channel #4] Channel created" module=grpc                                                                                     
[Channel #4] original dial target is: \"unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock\"" module=grpc                                 
[Channel #4] parsed dial target is: {Scheme:unix Authority: Endpoint:run/containerd/containerd.sock URL:{Scheme:unix Opaque: $
ser: Host: Path:/run/containerd/containerd.sock RawPath: OmitHost:false ForceQuery:false RawQuery: Fragment: RawFragment:}}" module=grpc                                                                                            
[Channel #4] Channel authority set to \"localhost\"" module=grpc
[Channel #4] Resolver state updated: {\n  \"Addresses\": [\n    {\n      \"Addr\": \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\",\n
 \"ServerName\": \"\",\n      \"Attributes\": {},\n      \"BalancerAttributes\": null,\n      \"Type\": 0,\n      \"Metadata\": null\n    }\n  ],\n  \"ServiceConfig\": null,\n  \"Attributes\": null\n} (resolver returned new addr$
sses)" module=grpc
[Channel #4] Channel switches to new LB policy \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
[Channel #4 SubChannel #5] Subchannel created" module=grpc
[Channel #4 SubChannel #5] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc
[Channel #4 SubChannel #5] Subchannel picks a new address \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" to connect" module=grpc
[Channel #4] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING" module=grpc
[Channel #4 SubChannel #5] Subchannel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc
[Channel #4] Channel Connectivity change to READY" module=grpc
level=warning msg="Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man docked` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section." storage-driver=devicemapper
level=warning msg="Base device already exists and has filesystem ext4 on it. User specified filesystem  will be ignored." storage-driver=devicemapper
level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver devicemapper is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; update the the daemon configuration and explicitly choose this storage driver to continue using it; visit https://docs.docker.com/go/storage-driver/ for more information"
[Channel #1] Channel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN" module=grpc
[Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN" module=grpc
[Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel deleted" module=grpc
[Channel #1] Channel deleted" module=grpc
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: prior storage driver devicemapper is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; update the the daemon configuration and explic$
tly choose this storage driver to continue using it; visit https://docs.docker.com/go/storage-driver/ for more information
```

What is the main error message here? I guess:

> storage driver devicemapper is deprecated

I tried editing `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` adding  `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev
```

Then call `systemctl daemon-reload` but this didn't help, it seems like The `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` option is not supported in Docker Community Edition (CE) version 5:23.0.0-1.

Comment: The last two lines seem pretty clear: you were using a graphdriver which has been deprecated and is now disabled by default. If you want to continue using it, you need to update docker configuration to force docker to use devicemapper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Storage-Driver `devicemapper` is deprecated and was disabled by the last update. You should set the storage driver to `overlay2`.

Open the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (if it does not exist, create it) and add the following JSON string:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Then restart docker:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

**Attention**! The existing containers don't survive the change of the storage-driver, so you have to re-run all `docker-compose` files that will rebuild the containers with the new driver.

Comment: If you don't want your existing containers to be destroyed, set `storage-driver` to `devicemapper` explicitly in that file. That should only be used temporary to retrieve data from these containers before moving to `overlay2` though.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go this way so this is **untested**. Please feedback me here if this worked for you.

If you urgently need the old containers, because there is data inside that wasn't mounted as volume, you could re-enable the old storage-driver in your service file: `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

Change the `ExecStart` line and add `--storage-driver devicemapper` so  e.g.:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --storage-driver devicemapper
```

then

```
systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart docker
```